# Magento 2 : Checkout Page Optimization Steps

Tags: checkout, onestepcheckout, magento2.4.6, speedoptimization

> Hey guys, I am working on checkout optimization and I am little bit
> stuck what steps should I follow to make my checkout load time lesser,
> thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The optimization is depend on the current development of the page and there components.

1. First you have to test the page into various optimization tools like `Light House` of crome browser.
2. On testing you will get report of those page.
3. Based on that report you need to take action to resolve or reduce those things.
4. Then you will get the good page speed for those page.

Comment: brother it is checkout page, how can i add product  through gt matrix or any other tool ?checkout will be empty and redirect to cart page if no products are added so if i try to check speed for checkout page it will show me cart page analytics.

Comment: I update the answer kindly check, If answer help then upvote and accept as solutions, so that will help other into community.